# How to add a limit in the generator expression Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I have a function in Python which returns true if all rows or columns in a grid matrix are the same value. 
However, I want my function to stop iterating and return True as soon as 4 of them match, irrespective of the size of the grid. How can I modify the generator expression I have below to achieve the same?

```
def check_won(grids, user, n):
    return any(all(cell == user for cell in grid) for grid in grids)
```

To illustrate further, I am sharing my example output:

```
Input the grid size: 5
Current board:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Input a slot player 1 from 1 to 5: 1
Current board:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Input a slot player 2 from 1 to 5: 2
Current board:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
Input a slot player 1 from 1 to 5: 1
Current board:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
Input a slot player 2 from 1 to 5: 2
Current board:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
Input a slot player 1 from 1 to 5: 1
Current board:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
Input a slot player 2 from 1 to 5: 2
Current board:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
Input a slot player 1 from 1 to 5: 1
Current board:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
Input a slot player 2 from 1 to 5: 2
Current board:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
Input a slot player 1 from 1 to 5: 1
Current board:
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
Player 1 has won
```

As can be seen this doesn't exit with 4 matches (match 4), but needs the whole column (5 elements shown here) or row to match.

Comment: It's not a list comprehension, and it does stop iterating as soon as it finds a match (and the inner `all` check also stops iterating as soon as it finds a non-match). In fact, it's specifically *because* you are not using list comprehensions (but instead *generator expressions*) that `any` and `all` are able to short-circuit in this way.

Comment: Oh, hold on. You want to look for at least 4 matches within a given `grid` list, and stop once you have 4?

Comment: You posted a function, not a method.  Methods belong to classes.  Ordinary methods take `self` as their first argument.

Comment: Please provide example input data for both expected return values.

Comment: You say "true if all rows or columns in a grid matrix are the same value", yet your function returns `True` if any of the rows has `user` on all positions, but doesn't check columns at all? Are you trying to write "Match 4", in which case you're just looking for 4 of the same values in a straight line, horizontal, vertical or diagonal?

Comment: This is not a list comprehension, but all these related "comprehension" constructs, list comprehension, generator expression (what you are working with here), dictionary comprehension, set comprehension ... they are designed to express mapping/filtering operations, and provide no clean way to exit early. That is generally up to whatever is *consuming* the result of these expressions. You could write a consumer for your generator expression that ends as soon as four true values are produced, and this would work well with the lazy evaluation of generators

Comment: I have updated the description. Yes I am looking for Match 4.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How would that look? Can you show me an example. I am pretty new with generators and consumers. So far my consumer looks like this: 

        
```if (check_won(grids, user, n) or
                check_won(zip(*grids), user, n) or
                diagcheck_won(grids, user, n) or
                diagcheck_won(grids[::-1], user, n)):
            print('Player', user, 'has won')
            return```

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes that's correct I want to look for at least 4 matches within a given grid list, and stop once I have 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any instead of all actually works in this case. All is just printing 1 for all the rows/ columns.

```
def check_won(grids, user, n):
    cnt = 0
    for grid in grids:
        if any(cell == user for cell in grid):
            cnt += 1
            if cnt == 4:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Your previous solution works if I replace all with any. ```if any(cell == user for cell in grid):```

Comment: @coderWorld But you want to match 4 that's consecutive that's why I chose this instead

Comment: No I wanted to match 4 in a row. My diagonal check is as follows: 
```def diagcheck_won(grids, user, n):
    return all(grids[x][x] == user for x in range(4))```

Comment: @coderWorld That only matches grids[0][0], grids[1][1], grids[2][2], grids[3][3]. What about grids[x][x] where x is 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Oh. You're right! Any suggestions to perhaps improve the diagonal check above as well? Also, please switch back to the previous answer using any, that one is working as expected. I will accept it.

Comment: It should be `any`. All is not working in this case.